# Can I use "it" to refer the plural noun "the fees"?

Tags: pronouns, singular-vs-plural

> You can pay the fees now; otherwise, you can pay it tomorrow.

Can I use "it" to refer the plural noun "the fees"?

Answer (score 2):

"...pay them tomorrow." Fees is countable and so, needs a plural pronoun.

Comment: are you suggesting that using _'it'_ in this context is incorrect?

Comment: @VarunKN, Yes, I am. It might be used colloquially and idiomatically, but grammatically, it's not correct.

Comment: As an aside, in your original sentence, I would have said, "You can pay the fees now or (you can pay them) tomorrow." I would not have used "otherwise" in the way that you had. "Otherwise" implies "or else," but here, you're just offering the person a choice, not giving them an ultimatum.

Comment: Another note, if referring to only one fee `You can pay the fee now, otherwise you can pay it tomorrow` would be correct. I'm sure this seems obvious but someone may miss it.

Comment: @MichaelCurry Good catch!